# HTML Form: Other input required ONLY if other is selected

Tags: html, checkbox, forms

I'm currently working on a form with a bunch of options. On some of the questions, there is an "Other" option for the user to type in whatever they choose. I am trying to make it appear only "Other" is selected (I've gotten this to work on the first question but not the others). I am also trying to make this input required ONLY if they select it, so that they can't submit the form having selected "Other" and left it blank.

Here is my HTML and the Javascript for making the other text inputs appear when selected:

```
<label for="Accom">Question</label>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><select name="Accom">
                <option value="">Select...</option>
                <option value="Handicapped">Handicap Accessibility</option>
                <option value="Hearing Impaired">Hearing Impaired</option>
                <option value="Visually Impaired">Visually Impaired</option>
                <option value="OtherAccom">Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <label style="" id="other">If Other, Please Specify
                <input type="text" name="Other_Accom" size="20"></label></td><tr></table>
```

.

```
window.onload=function() {
var other = document.getElementById('other', 'otherAccom','otherDiet');;
other.style.display = 'none';
document.getElementsByName('Title', 'Diet', 'Accom')[0].onchange = function() {other.style.display =(this.value=='Other')? '' : 'none'};
```

I'm also trying to get a this to work for a checkbox form.

```
<label for="Interests">Question</label><br>
            <input class="checkbox2" TYPE="checkbox" NAME="formInterests[]" required value="Use Cases ||" />Use Cases<br>
            <input class="checkbox2" TYPE="checkbox" NAME="formInterests[]" required value="Other" />Other<br>
            <label style="" id="other">If Other, Please Specify
                <input type="text" name="Other_Interests" size="20"></label>
```

Thank you very much!

EDIT 1: When I try and duplicate the function, it stops working for everything.

```
window.onload=function() {
var other = document.getElementById('other', 'otherAccom', 'otherDiet');;
other.style.display = 'none';
document.getElementsByName('Title')[0].onchange = function() {other.style.display = (this.value=='Other')? '' : 'none'};
};

window.onload=function() {
var otherDiet = document.getElementById('other', 'otherAccom', 'otherDiet');;
otherDiet.style.display = 'none';
document.getElementsByName('Diet')[0].onchange = function() {otherDiet.style.display = (this.value=='OtherDiet')? '' : 'none'};
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> document.getElementsByName('Title', 'Diet', 'Accom')[0].onchange = function() {other.style.display =(this.value=='Other')? '' : 'none'};

This selects an array of elements, which you then access by [0], meaning you target the first element (which will be the first of the three that appears in the DOM), and add the onChange listener to it.
This results, as you said yourself:

> (I've gotten this to work on the first question but not the others)

Because you actually only run the code on one of the three elements.

You should instead use something like:

```
document.getElementsByName('Title', 'Diet', 'Accom').forEach(function(element) {
  element.onChange = function() {
    var target = document.getElementById('Other'+this.name);
    if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value=='Other') {
      target.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      target.style.display = 'none';
    }
  };
});
```

The basic idea is using a forEach to loop through ALL your desired elements, rather than just one of them.

Keep in mind that:

> <option value="OtherAccom">Other</option>

does not have value="Other", but value="OtherAccom". Make sure your javascript and html are consistent with eachother.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I tried using the JS you put in but it doesn't seem to be working...do I need to add "style: display: none;" to each of the html options so they don't show up by default?

Comment: are you making sure to wrap it in:
`window.onload=function() { }`, so it actually runs? and also making sure to adjust your elements id's to match what the function will be looking for? (OtherTitle, OtherDiet and OtherAccom)

Comment: It is wrapped yes, and I adjusted the element ID's as well. It doesn't work at all now with what you wrote. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Also do you have any idea how to make this required for the user to fill out? I haven't been able to figure that out yet.

Comment: edited my response slightly, to make sure you're getting the proper value from the dropdowns. If this still doesn't work, i'll probably need to see more of the code to test it myself. As with most javascript, it's all about finding the 1 line that chokes it all, and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use IDs only *once* on a page ("other")

you need to rename those other "others" and create seperate functions for them

Comment: I've tried doing that, when I create separate functions the original one that I have working stops working and so none of them work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AngeloS Hard to tell, maybe you could update the code?

Comment: @AngeloS In the code above you still have TWO different elements (label) that have the same ID (= "other"). that won't work...
Also, to make it clearer for yourself, I would copy the function three times (= 3 functions). In each of them, just do the whole script for ONE of the option groups. Be careful to write ID atrributes into the elements, not just names. And be careful to use every ID just once on the whole page. In each of the 3 functions, you have to adress *different* IDs...